# Split classes and inheritance in header in c ++, error

Tags: c++

Could someone give me an example of how to inherit in c ++ using classes and header?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Book.h"
#include "Libro.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    Book book1(10);
    book1.setBookId();
    cout << book1.getBookId()<<"\n";
    
    
    Libro libr();
    libr.getBookId();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `Libro libr();` to `Libro libr;`

Comment: Your question would be better on topic question at StackOverflow if you showed your code and error. [mcve]

Comment: If you want us look at how to use your classes and headers, it would be good if you have also posted those files.

Comment: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/inheritance/intro/

Answer (score 0):

You have C++'s most vexing parse problem:

```
Libro libr();
```

is seen as the declaration of a function called `libr` taking no parameteras and returning a `Libro` object.

Instead write:

```
Libro libr;
```

to create an object called `libr` of `class` `Libro`.